# Unity2D: Inventory system - instantiated prefabs appearing in front of original object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've created a inventory system that works, however I'm having trouble with the instantiated prefabs. Basically the user is given two items (item1 & item2) at the beginning; if they would like to they can buy an extra item (lets day item2) to place down, however the area where the item can be placed down has a limit (4). If the items within the area gets above 4, all of the items are sent back to their slots except for the instantiated prefabs, they are sent to an empty gameObject.

My problem:

Say like I placed two of item 2 (the original and the prefab instantiated) down and then placed down three of item 1 down all of the items will be sent back, then after dragging item 2 into the area, when I proceed to try and drag item 1 (original obj) to the area it appears to be dragging the instantiated prefab rather than the original obj making the original obj change sizes and changes order in layer.

My script:

```
private Vector3 screenPoint;
private Vector3 offset;
public Transform item1, item2;
public GameObject otherItems,otherItems2

void Awake() {
    item1 = GameObject.FindWithTag ("item1").transform;
    item2 = GameObject.FindWithTag ("item2").transform;
}

void OnMouseDrag()
{
    //if (canDrag == true) {
        Vector3 curScreenPoint = new Vector3 (Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, screenPoint.z);
        screenPoint.z = 10;
        Vector3 curPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (curScreenPoint); // + offset

        transform.position = curPosition;
    //}
}
void Update()
{

    //1
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp (0)) {
        if (!GameObject.Find ("Aera Floor").GetComponent<SlotController> ().item1Placed) {
            item1.localPosition = Vector3.zero;
            rend1.sortingOrder = 1;
            //otherItems.SetActive (false);
        } else if (GameObject.Find ("Aera Floor").GetComponent<SlotController> ().item1Placed) {
            screenPoint = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint (gameObject.transform.position);
            rend1.sortingOrder = -1;
            otherItems.SetActive (true);
            //canDrag = false;
        }
    }

    //2
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp (0)) {
        if (!GameObject.Find ("Aera Floor").GetComponent<SlotController> ().item2Placed) {
            item2.localPosition = Vector3.zero;
            rend2.sortingOrder = 1;
            //otherItems2.SetActive (false);
        } else if (GameObject.Find ("Aera Floor").GetComponent<SlotController> ().item2Placed) {
            screenPoint = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint (gameObject.transform.position);
            rend2.sortingOrder = -1;
            otherItems2.SetActive (true);
            //slotHolder.SetActive (true);
            //canDrag = false;
        }
    }
    if (GameObject.Find ("Aera Floor").GetComponent<SlotController> ().item1Placed) {
        if (GameObject.Find ("Aera Floor").GetComponent<SlotController> ().item2Placed) {
            slotHolder.SetActive (true);
        }
    if (GameObject.Find ("Aera Floor").GetComponent<SlotController> ().item2Placed) {
        if (GameObject.Find ("Aera Floor").GetComponent<SlotController> ().item1Placed) {
            slotHolder.SetActive (true);
        } 
    }
```

Script for instantiated the prefabs:

```
public void InstaniateItem() {
    GameObject item = (GameObject)Instantiate (ItemPrefab);
    item.transform.position = transform.position;
    item.transform.parent = transform;
    item.SetActive (true);
    if (slot.childCount < 0) {
        slotHolder.SetActive (false);
    }
}
```

Extra info:

- All of the prefabs has the same tags as the original items.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a rule, try to cache the results of `GameObject.Find()` since it hogs performance and, in your case, it makes the code really cluttered. See [the documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.Find.html) for more info.

Your problem might be coming from the double `if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))` clause. This is actually called every time you release a click, so your checks are done for both items on every click. If you're already having issues with two items, what happens when you have three or four? Maybe you should rethink your approach.

Below is the equivalent of your code, hope it helps you gain some clarity on what's going on.

```
void Awake() {
    item1 = GameObject.FindWithTag ("item1").transform;
    item2 = GameObject.FindWithTag ("item2").transform;
    SlotController slotCtrl = GameObject.Find ("Aera Floor").GetComponent<SlotController> ();
}

void Update()
{

if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp (0)) {
    if (!slotCtrl.item1Placed) {
        item1.localPosition = Vector3.zero;
        rend1.sortingOrder = 1;
        //otherItems.SetActive (false);
    } else  {
        screenPoint = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint (gameObject.transform.position);
        rend1.sortingOrder = -1;
        otherItems.SetActive (true);
        //canDrag = false;
    }

    if (slotCtrl.item2Placed) {
        item2.localPosition = Vector3.zero;
        rend2.sortingOrder = 1;
        //otherItems2.SetActive (false);
    } else {
        screenPoint = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint (gameObject.transform.position);
        rend2.sortingOrder = -1;
        otherItems2.SetActive (true);
        //slotHolder.SetActive (true);
        //canDrag = false;
    }
}

if (slotCtrl.item1Placed && slotCtrl.item2Placed) {
        slotHolder.SetActive (true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, your script worked!!!!!! I had to modify it a bit tho but overall I couldn't of done it without your help! Thank you!!!!

Comment: Glad to help :)